# SQL AFTER UPDATE and DELETE trigger fired in sequence

Tags: java, sql, oracle, database-trigger

I am facing a strange problem while working with SQL triggers.

Java Code:

1. Updates a record in a table (Doing this to update App User, a column in database)
2. After update, delete the same record.
3. Both update and delete is part of a transaction.

Trigger:

1. For this table, we have a trigger which inserts a entry into AUD table for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operation.

What is happening:

1. When java code executes, it update the record and delete is also successful in the main table.
2. But AUD table has entry just for UPDATE and DELETE AUD entry is missing.
3. The moment, I add a sleep between update and delete java code, all works fine, entry is made into AUD table for both update and delete operation.

Please help me as I am not able find out any solution for this on internet.

UPDATE(Trigger Code) :-

```
         CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ISF.MATRIX_TEAM_STRATEGY_AUD_AR_TR
         AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
         ON ISF.MATRIX_TEAM_STRATEGY
       REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
      FOR EACH ROW
       DECLARE
      v_upd_login varchar2(30);
      insert_error EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(insert_error, -20501);
     v_action_cd CHAR(1);
        begin
     IF INSERTING THEN
       v_action_cd :=  'I';
         ELSIF UPDATING THEN
       v_action_cd := 'U';
       ELSE
       v_action_cd := 'D';
   END IF;

        -- get the user id;
        select user into v_upd_login from dual;
        -- add an audit record

    if inserting or updating then
        insert into isf.matrix_team_strategy_aud
               (
    TEAM_STRATEGY_ID,
    TEAM_ID,
    STRATEGY_ID,
    PORTFOLIO_LIST_ID,
    SUB_TEAM_ID,
    INS_TS,
    UPD_TS,
    INS_LOGIN,
    UPD_LOGIN,
    APP_USER,
    ACTION_CD
         )
        values
               (
    :new.TEAM_STRATEGY_ID,
    :new.TEAM_ID,
    :new.STRATEGY_ID,
    :new.PORTFOLIO_LIST_ID,
    :new.SUB_TEAM_ID,
    :new.INS_TS,
    :new.UPD_TS ,
    :new.INS_LOGIN,
    v_upd_login,
    :new.APP_USER,
    v_action_cd
    );
    elsif deleting then
        insert into isf.matrix_team_strategy_aud
                (
    TEAM_STRATEGY_ID,
    TEAM_ID,
    STRATEGY_ID,
    PORTFOLIO_LIST_ID,
    SUB_TEAM_ID,
    INS_TS,
    UPD_TS,
    INS_LOGIN,
    UPD_LOGIN,
    APP_USER,
    ACTION_CD
         )
        values
               (
    :old.TEAM_STRATEGY_ID,
    :old.TEAM_ID,
    :old.STRATEGY_ID,
    :old.PORTFOLIO_LIST_ID,
    :old.SUB_TEAM_ID,
    :old.INS_TS,
    sysdate,
    :old.INS_LOGIN,
    v_upd_login,
    :old.APP_USER,
    v_action_cd
);
    end if;
exception
    when dup_val_on_index then
        null;
    when others then
        raise_application_error(-20501,'Insert error ' || sqlerrm);
--      dbms_output.put_line ('Error in audit trigger of isf.matrix_team_strategy_aud Sql code ' ||sqlcode || ' ' ||sqlerrm);
end;
```

Comment: How is the trigger defined? Include the code in your post.

Comment: My guess is that an exception is raised within the trigger itself(for the AFTER DELETE event). This exception may be due to locking (or something else) but in real world scenarios you will (almost) never update and immediately delete a record so this doesn't seem to be an issue at all.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create trigger` statement for the table in question. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Include the ddl for AUD table as well, there may be some unique key based on date/time that needs to be verified.

Comment: What is a purpose of `when dup_val_on_index then null;` declaration ? Are there any unique keys/indexes on `matrix_team_strategy_aud` table ? If yes, then in case of duplicate index the error is swallowed and the row is not inserted.